# Create a Scala DSL where state is available within a block without being declared as a parameter?

Tags: scala, dsl

I have some vanilla Scala code that looks like this:

```
addCooker(new Cooker(getOvenState(), cookingTime, CookieNames.GingerSnaps) {
  override def cook(customer: Customer, priority: Priority): Boolean = {
    // Use `customer` and `priority` to cook a cookie and return true if successful.
    ???
  }
})
```

I.e. I create a callback-like `Cooker` object that's passed to an `addCooker` method. `CookieCutter` takes some values (`cookingTime` etc.) that are available when calling `addCooker` (these are passed to its ctor) and it takes some values (`customer` etc.) that will only be available at some later point in time (these will be passed as arguments to its `cook` method).

I'd like to create a **DSL** where I can write this as:

```
addCooker(getOvenState(), cookingTime, CookieNames.GingerSnaps) {
  // Somehow make a `customer` and `priority` value (that are not available at
  // the time `addCooker` happens) visible to the code within this block.
}
```

I could declare `addCooker` as a method like so:

```
def addCooker(overState: OvenState, cookingTime: Duration, name: CookieName)(
  block: () => Boolean
): Unit = ???
```

But I don't see a way to make `cookingTime` etc. available such that they can be used within the lambda passed as `block`.

The best I can do results in something like this:

```
addCooker(getOvenState(), cookingTime, CookieNames.GingerSnaps) { (customer, priority) =>
  true
}
```

Normally, this would be good enough for me but in this situation, hundreds of such blocks will be written (and there'll be lots of different but similar constructs) and a DSL where many of the values are *just there* rather than one needing to always declare them as parameters would be ideal.

I guess one way is to make `customer` etc. `protected var` variables of the class where the `addCooker` calls are being made, i.e. they'd be visible not just to my `{ ... }` block but also to the logic that calls `addCooker`  (but without yet being set to anything meaningful).

**PS** are there any good guides to the kinds of non-obvious tricks that you need to use to create DSLs? I found lots of guides that didn't go very deep (focusing on little more than using implicits to do type conversions or do fun things with operators). The only substantial thing I found was [DSLs in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/dsls-in-action) but it was written in 2010 and uses Scala 2.8 - I imagine the thinking on many things related to implicits and the like has changed noticeably since then.

---

If the above snippets are unclear, you can them (with supporting stubs such that things will compile) here:

https://gist.github.com/george-hawkins/a9db64f05e14ea7d191bc4cf85dd64f6